# nested divs negative zindex

Tags: html, css, forms, z-index

Suppose I have a nested div structure as follows,

```
<div id="A">
  <div id="B" style='z-index: -1; position: relative;'>
    <input type='text' />
  </div>
</div>
```

where the child of div A is required to have a z-index of -1 for formatting purposes (I need div B to change the size of div A, I need div B to be inside of div B's bounderies, but div B must also be below div A). The problem I have is that I can't seem to access the input elements on my forms, like shown in the following JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Urn4/

I've tried wrapping the input in it's own div and setting it back to a higher z-index, but because each z-index seems to be relative to the parent, this ultimately proves futile. So how would I go about reformatting the html/css to achieve the same effect as before, without breaking my forms/links?

Comment: full confusion. if you want z-index:-1 for div A then go and directly add it in div A. why you have assigned to div B?

Comment: remove position:relative property. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you need remove `position:relative;`

Comment: That's true, but that also disables z-index, as z-index must always be paired off with a position attribute.